# Can Maven be configured to compile Java 1.x code by default?

Tags: maven, java

I'm setting up a Jenkins server on Ubuntu using Maven 3.0.5 and OpenJDK 7. Maven insists on compiling with Java 1.3 as described in various other questions. I've spent hours poring over dozens of pages about this bizarre behavior and it always comes back to one thing: specify a specific Java target for the compile plugin with a big block of xml in every POM:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

It seems directly contradictory to Maven's "convention over configuration" mantra to have to explicitly tell it you're using modern Java for every project. Surely the convention isn't to expect Java 1.3 code, and to manually keep every pom.xml in sync with the installed JDK otherwise. Isn't there some way to configure *Maven* rather than configuring every *project*?

Answer (score 1):

If all poms inherit from a common *parent*, which is an extremely common structure, you may specify in the parent only once.

I don't believe what you're asking for is configurable, nor should it be. It would break the portability of your build which is the point of Maven. If you did do it your way, you would also need to put the global maven configuration under source control, because otherwise it's not possible to look at the repository alone and know what version it should be compiled under.

IOW another important design principle is "all build configuration goes in the pom." You are proposing another layer of configuration, a global setting to span projects that otherwise aren't related to each other.

Comment: I'm not sure how easily inheritance will work in my case (pulling from several unrelated GitHub repos to build them individually) but that is certainly preferable to duplicating it. Surprised that it wasn't mentioned in the solutions I found.

Comment: @TravisChristian do those projects have poms already? Note that it's not actually duplication if the projects don't know about each other. Better behavior for Maven might be to just fail if not specified, arguably.

Comment: Re: portability, it seems like "assume a 14-year-old spec" is less useful and portable than "use whatever is installed" which is really what I'd like it to do.

Comment: They don't, it's kind of an odd situation but ultimately the poms are specifically for the build server. I'm mostly just frustrated with having to manually add this to each pom to be able to compile anything.